# Disable scrolling in browser control for WP7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

Is it possible to disable the scrolling in a web browser control in Windows Phone 7.1? I have seen quite a few questions ask around it (Windows Phone 7.0, Silverlight) but an answer has yet to come up. Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't need interaction with the control, you can just set IsHitTextVisible = false, and if you do, you can set ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBar = Disabled

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [blog post here](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control/) explaining how to suppress the zoom and scroll functionality of the WebBrowser control. Quote from that post:

> The visual tree is quite simple, composed of a few grids and borders.
>   The significant parts are the TileHost, which is the native IE9
>   component, and the PanZoomContainer. The TileHost does not handle the
>   mouse manipulation events, these are instead handled by the
>   PanZoomContainer, where they are then translated into gestures (i.e.
>   pinch-zoom) with the result fed back to the TileHost.
>
> What this means is that we can intercept the manipulation events as
>   they bubble up to the PanZoomContainer, cancelling them before they
>   are turned into gestures.

Answer (score 2):

Given the webbrowser:

To disable interaction set `IsHitTextVisible`= false

```
<phone:WebBrowser Height="600" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
```

To disable scrolling only, set `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility`= disabled

```
<phone:WebBrowser Height="600" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
```

Comment: the scrolling controls rendered in the webbrower cannot be controlled by the Scrollviewer property , it should be controlled by injecting  JavaScript code  to dynamically set the  content to the available view port