# Bouncing BrowserControl within a ScrollView

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control, scrollview

I got a BIG problem with a BrowserControl in Windows Phone 7.

The structure looks like this

- ScrollView

  - Pictures
  - BrowserControl
  - Buttons

The BrowserControl (BC) is inside a ScrollView (SV) like you see. The BC is changing it's height flexible and is partially outside of the screen.

We need the following solution:
The BC should scroll like simultaneously like the elements. The content of the BC shouldn't scroll. BUT links inside the BC should be clickable.

Sorry for my poor english ;)

Hope you can help me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable scrolling in browser control for WP7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218107/disable-scrolling-in-browser-control-for-wp7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This article might be usefull : "Suppressing Zoom and Scroll interactions in the Windows Phone 7 WebBrowser Control"
http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control/