# Disable Scrolling in WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, image, windows-8, webbrowser-control

I have a webpage that displays one large image. I wrote an app that requires that image. I tried saving that image to a webpage, using  in the app, but I want the functionality to refresh that image when coming back to the same view, or every 15 seconds. However, it seems like the WebBrowser box is actually much easier to refresh and it also automatically refreshes when you enter the view.

**I want to fixate the WebBrowser box so that the user cannot scroll**, to just frame the image. Any ideas on how can I achieve that, or prohibit interaction with the WebBrowser box?

Here is the XAML

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name ="Camera1" Source ="uri goes here" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Margin="10,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="247" Width="439"/>
```

Comment: Is the webbrowser control from Winforms, WPF or elsewhere?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure. I simply implemented it rhough the toolbox (drag and drop) so I guess WPF.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I Just figured it out with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218107/disable-scrolling-in-browser-control-for-wp7) post and the Mod for modifying my question so appropriately.

Quote:

> Given the webbrowser:
>
> To disable interaction set IsHitTextVisible= false
>
> ```
> <phone:WebBrowser Height="600" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
> ```
>
> To disable scrolling only, set ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility= disabled
>
> ```
> <phone:WebBrowser Height="600" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
> ```

Answer (score -1):

The below setting is not disabling vertical scroll in WebBrowser in Windows...how do we make the browser not scroll up / down when user slides on LCD? I am implementing Signature App.

To disable scrolling only, set ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility= disabled

Comment: Don't use an answer to ask a further question, please ask a new question